How can I determine if I am on the home screen in Ubuntu 20.04?
How can I programmatically detect when the focused window is displaying the home screen (i.e., no other windows are focused, such as after pressing Super+D)? I'm developing an application and couldn't find clear information on how to implement this functionality.

Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more context. What desktop environment is this expected to work with? Gnome? Cinnamon? KDE? Something else? All of them? What protocol? X11? Wayland? What exactly is a "home screen"? Do you mean the Desktop? So this will only be targeting systems that have a "Desktop" (so no tiling window managers for instance)? If you have a focused window, how can it also be showing the desktop?
